# PostgreSQL 9.5: Append export data into text file

Tags: postgresql

I want to export the selected records into the text file.

## Using:

```
\COPY (SELECT * FROM Table_Name) TO '/root/Exported_Data.txt'
```

**Note**: The above script just giving me same records, **BUT NOT** appending any duplicate or non duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link might help in appending data to a file using *copy* command: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149745/copy-command-in-postgresql-to-append-data/149774#149774